# How to decrypt password

Tags: c#, .net-core, encryption, passwords

This is my .NET core API controller.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Linq;
using Vantage.Core.Direct.BL;
using Vantage.Core.Direct.DAL.Models;
using VANTAGE_Dashboard.API.Helper;

namespace Vantage.Core.Direct.API.Controllers
{
    [Route("[controller]")]
     
    [ApiController]
    public class LoginController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly VantageContext _context;
        public LoginController(VantageContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        [HttpPost("login")]
         
        public IActionResult Login([FromBody] AvLogin avLogin)
        {
            if (avLogin == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            else {
                // var user = _context.AvLogins.Where(a => a.Id == avLogin.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                var user = _context.AvLogins.Where(a =>
                 a.Id == avLogin.Id && a.PasswordHash == avLogin.PasswordHash).FirstOrDefault();
                if (user != null)
                {
                    return Ok(new
                    {
                        StatusCode = 200,
                        Message = "Logged in Successfully"

                    });
                }
                else 
                
                {
                    return NotFound(new
                    {
                        StatusCode = 404,
                        Message= "User Not Found"
                    }) ;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my decryption class

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Vantage.DataAccessLayer
{
    public class MD5Encryption
    {
        private static readonly string SecurityKey = "http://www.2am5ana.c0m";
        // Hash an input string and return the hash as
        // a 32 character hexadecimal string.
        public static string GetMd5Hash(string input)
        {
            // Create a new instance of the MD5CryptoServiceProvider object.
            MD5 md5Hasher = MD5.Create();

            // Convert the input string to a byte array and compute the hash.
            byte[] data = md5Hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(input));

            // Create a new Stringbuilder to collect the bytes
            // and create a string.
            StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            // Loop through each byte of the hashed data 
            // and format each one as a hexadecimal string.
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
            }

            // Return the hexadecimal string.
            return sBuilder.ToString();
        }

        public static string Encrypt(string toEncrypt, bool useHashing)
        {
            byte[] keyArray;
            byte[] toEncryptArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toEncrypt);

            //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(key);
            //If hashing use get hashcode regards to your key
            if (useHashing)
            {
                MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashmd5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
                keyArray = hashmd5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SecurityKey));
                //Always release the resources and flush data
                // of the Cryptographic service provide. Best Practice

                hashmd5.Clear();
            }
            else
                keyArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SecurityKey);

            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            //set the secret key for the tripleDES algorithm
            tdes.Key = keyArray;
            //mode of operation. there are other 4 modes.
            //We choose ECB(Electronic code Book)
            tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            //padding mode(if any extra byte added)

            tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateEncryptor();
            //transform the specified region of bytes array to resultArray
            byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0,
              toEncryptArray.Length);
            //Release resources held by TripleDes Encryptor
            tdes.Clear();
            //Return the encrypted data into unreadable string format
            return Convert.ToBase64String(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length);
        }

        public static string Decrypt(string cipherString, bool useHashing)
        {
            byte[] keyArray;
            //get the byte code of the string

            byte[] toEncryptArray = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherString);            

            if (useHashing)
            {
                //if hashing was used get the hash code with regards to your key
                MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashmd5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
                keyArray = hashmd5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SecurityKey));
                //release any resource held by the MD5CryptoServiceProvider

                hashmd5.Clear();
            }
            else
            {
                //if hashing was not implemented get the byte code of the key
                keyArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SecurityKey);
            }

            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            //set the secret key for the tripleDES algorithm
            tdes.Key = keyArray;
            //mode of operation. there are other 4 modes. 
            //We choose ECB(Electronic code Book)

            tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            //padding mode(if any extra byte added)
            tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateDecryptor();
            byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(
                                 toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);
            //Release resources held by TripleDes Encryptor                
            tdes.Clear();
            //return the Clear decrypted TEXT
            return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultArray);
        }

        public static string DecryptEntityCon()
        {
            string connectionString = new System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnectionStringBuilder
            {
                Metadata = "res://*/VantageModel.csdl|res://*/VantageModel.ssdl|res://*/VantageModel.msl",
                Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient",
                ProviderConnectionString = MD5Encryption.Decrypt(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["VantageConnectionString"].ConnectionString, true) + ";MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
            }.ConnectionString;

            return connectionString;
        }
    }
}
```

now can login using userName-: admin  ,                                                                                                                                                          Password-: 2fe3cb9e21922819e79a2781af74e36d                                                                                                                but not decrypt value. how to connect both files decypt  password ?

Comment: Perhaps take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.tripledescryptoserviceprovider.-ctor?view=net-6.0)

Comment: You shuldn't ever encrypt or decrypt passwords. Store a salted hash instead. To compare, hash the password given by the user again and compare the hashes. This way, even if an attacker gets hold on the password file/database, he will be unable to retrieve the passwords.

Comment: Also, MD5 is too fast (meaning potential brute force / dictionary attacks can be attempted with a far greater chance of success within a reasonable timeframe) and unsalted (additional input in one-way encryption to combat, among others, dictionary attacks is missing) so it shouldn't be used in the first place. There are better, salted and slower encryption libs out there. Do some research on BCrypt and why multi-round, salted algorithms are much more secure.